# handle response from telegram bot api

Tags: node.js, promise, telegram-bot

I am using this api: https://github.com/orzFly/node-telegram-bot

It should work like any other.

Now I want my Bot to have an option to update a string he keeps for some reason. so on "/update" the update function is called, where *msg* is a Message object (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message):

```
link = "something";
function update(msg) {

    response = tg.sendMessage({
        text: "Send a new URL, please",
        chat_id: msg.chat.id,
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: {
            force_reply: true,
            selective: true
        }
    });
    console.log("response: " + response);
    // on reply I want to update link
}
```

Now this bot asks me to provide a new string. The next answer in telegram is already an answer to the bots request, because of the force_reply.
How would I get this answer? 'response' here is a promise object and I don't know what to do with it.

After reading about Promises objects, I tried something like this:

```
response.then(function successHandler(result) {
    tg.sendMessage({
        text: "new URL is: I don't know",
        chat_id: msg.chat.id
    });
}, function failureHandler(error) {
    colsole.log("error: " + error);
});
```

But it didn't work. In no way.

I just don't know where to get the reply Message object from.
I hope it's clear what I am asking. Otherwise let me know.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(result)` in that `then` handler?

Comment: yes. It gives me an "object Object" with no attribute 'text', which a Message should have.

Comment: Is that a string? Try `result.text` nonetheless.

Comment: result.text is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you're trying to get the next message from the user and treat it as the new string;
Problem is: response will contain the response from Telegram servers stating the result of the message you tried to send; it has nothing to do with the user's response to your message;

In order to do this, you need to control what was the last message your bot sent to a user and, based on that, decide how to handle that user's next message; it could look something like this:

```
link = "something";
states = {}
function update(msg) {
    if (!states[msg.chat.id] || states[msg.chat.id] == 1) {
        tg.sendMessage({
            text: "Send a new URL, please",
            chat_id: msg.chat.id,
            reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
            reply_markup: {
                force_reply: true,
                selective: true
            }
        }).then(() => {
            states[msg.chat.id] = 2
            console.log(`Asked a question to ${msg.chat.id}`);
        });
    } else {
        link = msg.text;
        tg.sendMessage({
            text: `New URL is: ${link}`,
            chat_id: msg.chat.id,
            reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the result in the promise is the entire response from Telegram. So your result will be in `result.result.text`

The `result` variable will look like:

```
{
    ok: true
    result: {
        message_id: x,
        from: { ... }
        chat: { ... }
        date: x,
        text: 'message'
    }
}
```

This is unfortunate, I would have suggested the author only returns the `result` key.

```
var api = require('telegram-bot');
api = new api(<TOKEN>);

api.sendMessage({ chat_id: 0, text: 'test' }).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});

api.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg); // <- will contain the reply
    // msg.text
    // msg.chat.id 
    // msg.from.id
});

api.start();
```

Comment: If you are looking for something that don't use promises, you can have a look at https://github.com/arcturial/telegrambot. It uses `function (err, result)` as a callback.

Comment: Couldn't get it working with result.result.text. It seems that the api I'm currently using does not support what I need. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I included an example of how I used that library, just in case it helps.

Comment: that would send 'test', but how would you handle the reply, when you use sendMessage with force_reply?

Comment: you mean when a user replies to a message you sent them in Telegram? not the response you get when you send a message to the API?

Comment: I added instructions on how to listen for new messages. You have to register an event and the `start` the library. I am pretty sure this uses the `getUpdates` Telegram call in the background. It will poll Telegram for new messages.

Comment: That's what I mean, thank you. This way I have to check myself if it is really a reply to the bots question. I thought there would be an easier way. Failed to check msg.reply_to_message.message_id.